# Crazy looping over lists and split dataframes, while sending emails. 90% there.. need the final push

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop

I have a project dataframe

```
dummy <- data.frame("lead" = c("Sammy", "Dan", "Lawrence", "Sammy", "Dan", "Lawrence", "Lawrence", "Sammy"),
           "project" = c("project4", "project2", "project3", "project4", "project1",
                         "project2", "project1", "project3"), 
           "member" = c("John", "Allen", "Jacob", "Bob", "John", 
                        "John", "Allen", "Jacob"),
           "hours" = c(25, 30, 15, 20, 15, 34, 24, 35))
```

Which results in this output:

```
 lead  project member hours
1    Sammy project4   John    25
2      Dan project2  Allen    30
3 Lawrence project3  Jacob    15
4    Sammy project4    Bob    20
5      Dan project1   John    15
6 Lawrence project2   John    34
7 Lawrence project1  Allen    24
8    Sammy project3  Jacob    35
```

I then split this dataframe to group together both `lead` and `member`:

```
grouping <- dummy$lead
split_dum1 <- split(dummy, grouping)
grouping2 <- dummy$member
split_dum2 <- split(dummy, grouping2)
```

The goal is this:

1. Grab the first dataframe in the list
2. Put it into an html table that can be embedded into outlook and sent as an email

I have figured this part out.

```
for (i in 1:length(split_dum1)) {

  df_html <- print(xtable(split_dum1[[i]]), type = "html", print.results=FALSE, 
                   include.rownames = FALSE
```

The next goal:

1. Take the first dataframe in split_dum1 and pull the first item of the `member` column.
2. Based on this name, pull the dataframe from `split_dum2` that summarizes all of the projects that this member is participating in.
3. Put this dataframe of the `member` into a table that can be put into the same email as the previous item.

I have also figured this out. The entire loop for both parts of the goal.

```
for (i in 1:length(split_dum1)) {

  df_html <- print(xtable(split_dum1[[i]]), type = "html", print.results=FALSE, 
                   include.rownames = FALSE)
  employee_df <- list()

  for (j in 1:nrow(split_dum1[[i]])) {
    employee <- split_dum1[[i]]$Employee[j]
    employee_df <- ra_user20[ra_user20$Employee == employee,]

    df_html2[j] <- print(xtable(employee_df), type = "html", print.results=FALSE, 
                    include.rownames = FALSE)    
  }

  body <- paste0("<html>", df_html, "</html>")
  body3 <- paste0("<html>", df_html2, "</html>")
  body2 <- paste0("<p>", "Please see the table below for your assigned
                  project hours next week.", "</p>", body, body3)

  OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
  outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
  outMail[["To"]] = "ibell@cicerogroup.com"
  outMail[["subject"]] = paste0("Assigned Hours Over the Next 4 weeks")
  outMail[["HTMLbody"]] = body2
  ## send it
  outMail$Send()
}
```

The above code prints out 2 tables and send multiple emails. I need one email sent per project lead.

The main goal here is to send a table to the project leads with their projects and who is assigned (this works).
The second part is to send the table showing if the members on their teams, are also booked for other projects, and what those projects are.

It would look something like this within the body of the email:

```
lead  project member hours
1 Sammy project4   John    25
2 Sammy project4    Bob    20


     lead  project   member hours
1    Sammy project4   John    25
2      Dan project1   John    15
3 Lawrence project2   John    35

     lead  project   member hours
1    Sammy project4   Bob    20
```

Again, this should all appear within one email.

Sammy wants to know where his teams hours are being allocated besides his project.

Comment: And what is your question? What does not work with current code?

Answer (score 0):

Though the exact ask isn't quite clear to me, I think this is what you're looking for. Plug this into the first for-loop. Obviously you won't need to `print(df_html2)` but you should know what to do with the output to get in into your email.

```
df_html2 <- character(nrow(split_dum1[[i]]))
for(j in 1:nrow(split_dum1[[i]])){
  employee <- split_dum1[[i]]$member[j]
  employee_df <- dummy[dummy$member == employee,]
  df_html2[j] <- print(xtable(employee_df), type = "html", print.results=FALSE, 
                    include.rownames = FALSE) 
}

print(df_html2)
```

And to deal with the variable length of `body3` try:

```
body2 <- paste0("<p>", "Please see the table below for your assigned
                  project hours next week.", "</p>", body, paste(body3,collapse =" "))
```

Comment: So this is close. I still am not having the tables appear in the same email, but they are appearing as separate emails.

Comment: I'm still a little shaky on what you mean, but I think it's likely that you need to pull the email sending out of the inner for-loop. Additionally, now that you have several elements in `df_html2`, you may need to adjust the way you are putting those into the body of the email. If it's still confusing, update your question and I'll try again.

Comment: This is very confusing to explain online. Thanks for being patient and helping out. I updated the bottom part of the syntax. I'm having trouble printing out all of the dataframes within the email. the loop seems to only print the first team member and then moves on to the next project lead.

Comment: Added an update to my answer. Let me know how that works.